# JupyterLab: How to trigger a call back function to python backend from Javascript front end

Tags: jupyter-notebook, ipython, jupyter, jupyter-lab

I am trying to build a JupyterLab Widget extension

I create an 'example.js' file that holds a button execute and an 'example.py' which holds model information.

When I run the code bellow,

```
import ExampleWidget
from ExampleWidet import example
example.RunTool()
```

Creates a button,

I want to execute another python function in the backend from the button click event.

I am not able to find a way to implement this part please help.

thanks

**Update**

Python Code:

```
from ipywidgets import VBox, widget_serialization
from traitlets import Unicode, List, Dict, Instance
from ._frontend import module_name, module_version
#from .basewidget import BaseWidget



class ExampleUIOutput(UIOutput):
    """
    Widget used to render Python output in a UI
    """
    _model_name = Unicode('ExampleUIOutputModel').tag(sync=True)
    _model_module = Unicode(module_name).tag(sync=True)
    _model_module_version = Unicode(module_version).tag(sync=True)

    _view_name = Unicode('ExampleUIOutputView').tag(sync=True)
    _view_module = Unicode(module_name).tag(sync=True)
    _view_module_version = Unicode(module_version).tag(sync=True)

    name = Unicode('Python Results').tag(sync=True)

    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        # Initialize the child widget container
        self.appendix = VBox()

        UIOutput.__init__(self, **kwargs)
```

Javascript Code:

```
export class ExampleUIOutputModel extends UIOutputModel {
    defaults() {
        return Object.assign(Object.assign({}, super.defaults()), { _model_name: ExampleUIOutputModel.model_name, _model_module: ExampleUIOutputModel.model_module, _model_module_version: ExampleUIOutputModel.model_module_version, _view_name: ExampleUIOutputModel.view_name, _view_module: ExampleUIOutputModel.view_module, _view_module_version: ExampleUIOutputModel.view_module_version, name: 'Python Results' });
    }
}
ExampleUIOutputModel.model_name = 'ExampleUIOutputModel';
ExampleUIOutputModel.model_module = MODULE_NAME;
ExampleUIOutputModel.model_module_version = MODULE_VERSION;
ExampleUIOutputModel.view_name = 'ExampleUIOutputView';
ExampleUIOutputModel.view_module = MODULE_NAME;
ExampleUIOutputModel.view_module_version = MODULE_VERSION;
ExampleUIOutputModel.serializers = Object.assign(Object.assign({}, UIOutputModel.serializers), { appendix: {
        deserialize: (value, manager) => unpack_models(value, manager)
    } });
export class ExampleUIOutputView extends UIOutputView {
    constructor() {
        super(...arguments);
    }

    render() {
        const Hello = document.createElement('button')
        this.el.append(Hello)

        Hello.addEventListener("click", function() {
        
           console.log('Hello World');


    }, false);


    }
}
```

Utilities:

I have a python file `Utils.py` with the code for example

```
 def HelloWorld(name):
     print('Hello '+name)
```

I want when I click the button it executes this python code or any other python code.

Comment: Have you tried using [ipywidgets](https://ipywidgets.readthedocs.io/en/latest/)?

Comment: Thanks for your reply, I dint try because I am not able to find any example code there, can you provide an example code or a link that shows how ipywidgets can be used for this purpose?

Comment: Sure, happy to. Just to understand better: are you trying to execute a Python function or a JavaScript function? Could you provide a more detailed example of what you are trying to achieve with some pseudo code in appropriate language(s)?

Comment: I updated the Question, I hope now it will help to understand the context. thanks

Comment: Apologies to ask again, but I am just not sure: did you add the JavaScript code (model etc) in order to build a button, or is it that you already have this model and want to use the JavaScript code for something else but would also want to connect it to the button? I mean this all can be done using Python only so I am not sure if you actually **need** to go into writing custom widgets.

Comment: I mean if you are starting with Python code and want to end with executing a Python function, is this function: https://ipywidgets.readthedocs.io/en/latest/examples/Widget%20Events.html#Example not enough? I can certainly imagine many cases were you would want to create a custom widget, but I just want to make it super clear first so that we are not reinventing the wheel.

Comment: No, I didn't create this model just to add a button, it's just an example code, with my current project I am creating a job submission form that submits the job to a server, this form is also not simple form it has different components that I chose to introduce with javascript rather Python. Howerver I am quite new to javascript and it's my first JavaScript project. I decided to experiment with the file upload (I know the file upload widget also available in the JupyterLab widgets). I want to learn this process to implement something complex that we cant do with python based widgets. Thanks